# Can we generate a BOM that exports generated artifacts as dependencies out of a Maven project?

Tags: spring, maven, dependency-management, project-management

I have the following situation: I inherited a legacy system, built as a multi-module Maven project.

```
parent
  module1
    module 1.1 -> generates artifact 1.1
    module 2.2 -> generates artifact 1.2
  module2
    module 2.1
      module 2.1.1 -> generates artifact 2.1.1
      module 2.1.2 -> generates artifact 2.1.2
    module 2.2 -> generates artifact 2.2
  module3 -> generates artifact3
```

This is the current situation, ***and for a long list of reasons, it cannot be altered***.

Furthermore, these artifacts (their subsets or their totality) get consumed as dependencies by other projects. These projects are built by other teams using processes outside of my control, and it becomes a hassle to get everyone on board to consume the correct versions.

I'd love to be able to generate a BOM that lists each generated artifact as a dependency in a dependency management section, with the correct versions, then publish that one BOM for everyone else to consume.

Kinda like the [master/parent bom](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-framework-bom) published by the Spring Framework.

Then, it'd be voila! I could try to create the BOM manually, but I'd rather not do that.

The legacy project I inherited is not the only one with these challenges. If I could find an automated way to do this, that'd be a great win for me and my co-workers.

I don't find any references on how to generate one such bom.

I only see documentation on how to use one, or how to create one manually for a project's dependencies.

I don't see any documentation on how to generate one that lists/exports the artifacts *created* by the project (for others to consume.)

Thanks.

PS. This project is not the only one. There are other projects being built and consume like that in a nightmarish 11th-dimensional quantum-entangled hyper-spaghetti ball of dependency doom (wink, wink.)

Comment: If those modules a built not within a single go it's really the way to separate them into different git repositories. The question is: Why had been decided to be a single repo or a single multi module build?

Comment: The reasons are too long to explain and beyond my current ability to control (legacy code + different responsibility teams.)

Restructuring is not an option. It is a lot cheaper to live with the system as-is (even with the pains) than a re-structuring.